# When a ListBox is empty, the setter for that property never gets called

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a property as follows:

```
    [DisplayName("Children")]
    public List<long> ChildrenIds
    {
        get { return SelectedGroup.Children.Select(x => x.Id).ToList(); }
        set
        {
            foreach (long groupId in value)
            {
                if (groupId != 0 && !SelectedGroup.Children.Select(x => x.Id).Contains(groupId))
                {
                    var group = FactoryTools.Factory.Get<GroupLookup>(groupId);

                    if (group != null) SelectedGroup.AddChild(group);
                }
            }

            var childrenLooper = SelectedGroup.Children.ToList();
            foreach (var group in childrenLooper)
            {
                if (group.Id != 0 && !value.Contains(group.Id))
                {
                    SelectedGroup.Children.Remove(group);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This works great when I have at least 1 child selected in my standard `Razor Listbox`:

```
    <div class="oneThird">
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.ChildrenIds)
        @Html.ListBoxFor(x => x.ChildrenIds, ListHelper.GetGroupsMinusSelf(Model.SelectedGroup))
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.ChildrenIds)
    </div>
```

However, when I unselect all of the items in the above `ListBox`, the setter for this property never gets called and so those items never get removed... what is the best way to make sure that all of the items get removed?

Comment: There is a lot of stuff going on inside that setter. Do you think you could reproduce the behaviour using a simpler setter?

Comment: I added a breakpoint to the setter, and it never gets called when the ListBox is empty, it gets called just fine, and does what it should when the ListBox is not empty...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When no items are selected there's no data POSTed from the browser and ASP.NET MVC model binding has no value to set.

In other words, the model binder is saying: "I have no value to set, so it doesn't make sense for me to call the setter", whereas you are expecting it to say: "I have no value to set, but I will call Serj's setter with an empty list anyway".

The real issue here, though, is that you are pushing model binding past what it was designed for. Model binding is just supposed to turn the string representations of data in an HTTP request into strongly typed data. Hence, the model that you bind to should represent an HTML form or something similarly simple (yes, I know Microsoft is boasting that you can model bind to complex objects out of the box, but that only works well in the simplest of cases, TBH). Once the data is strongly typed, do your data processing in your action method (or business object, service, helper or whatever).

I would recommend that you

1) introduce something like a MyForm class like so:

```
public class MyForm 
{ 
  public IEnumerable<int> ChildrenIds { get;set; }
}
```

2) introduce a view model like so:

```
public class MyViewModel 
{
  public MyViewModel(Data somedata)
  {
    /* populate Options */
  }

  public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Options { get; set; }
  public MyForm Form { get; set; }
}
```

3) use this model in your view:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.Form.ChildrenIds, Model.Options)
```

4) and finally, for your action method you model bind to MyForm:

```
public ActionResult MyMethod(MyForm form)
{
  /* inspect POSTed form.ChildrenIds, add/remove from domain model etc. as you see fit */
}
```

This will give you a much cleaner separation of HTTP-concerns from business concerns.

Comment: I will give you the answer because you helped me find the solution, however I must say that the solution that you are presenting is asking me to write some fairly ugly code... I think I keep my model as is, change the getter/setter to the way that you have it, but write my setter code in the Save method of my model...

Comment: Glad I could help :-). I think you will find that, as your application and user interactions grow more complicated, my approach scales better than yours.